# Anchor links in php file point to index.html

Tags: php, html, yaml

I have a file `index.php` containing mostly HTML and a bit of PHP. I have declared `id`s for some elements (e.g., `<h2 id="contact">Contact</h2>`) and provide links to them (cf. below).

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The links work fine when clicked (i.e., the user is taken to the anchor point), but they point to, e.g., `index.html#contact`, so that when the page is reloaded, you get a 500 error.

How can this behaviour be avoided? And why does it occur anyhow?

I'm using the [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/) CSS framework btw.

Comment: What does your error log show you in the 500 error?

Comment: should be `<a name="contact">` not id

Comment: YAML does not use any server-side scripts, so it should not create any 500 error.

Comment: @Dagon html5 wants ids for that. `The <a> name attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use the id attribute instead.`

Comment: dam
 you html5, you have foiled me again.

Comment: @mts7: Sorry, I don't have access to the nginx error log. And yes, I'm using `id` cos that's what HTML5 wants ;).

Comment: @Cheery: Thanks for confirming YAML is out of the equation, would've thought so.

Comment: Ask you hosting provider what the error message is in the error log for nginx. Without that, this debugging is futile.

Comment: @mts7: Okay, will do.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Why don't you hack it with js :)

```
location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

*UPDATE END*

The hash (#) inside link means an "ID" of an element within the same page.

```
href="#id" .. means index.php/#id <-- scroll to an id element

href="link" .. means index.php/link <-- redirect to file called 'link'
```

Also you need in htaccess enable to redirect to file without file extension. e.g. php / html

**Your problem**

**Check your existing htaccess**

Comment: Does nginx use .htaccess like Apache httpd? I thought it didn't.

Comment: @ITPAL24: Well, the first example is just what I'm doing, isn't it? I'm linking to `id`s with `<a href="#contact">`

Comment: @QueNuevo - Please still check your htaccess, if you have file extension activated in htaccess it might think #contact is a file name..

Comment: nginx doesn't use htaccess, and I don't have access to the nginx config :(.

Comment: @QueNuevo - check if browser adding '/' on the end of a link ..e.g. #contact/?

Comment: @ITPAL24: Nope, it doesn't, plain `index.html#contact` :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<h2><a id="contact">Contact</a></h2>
```

or

```js
<script>

    function getPosition(element){
        var e = document.getElementById(element);
        var left = 0;
        var top = 0;

        do{
            left += e.offsetLeft;
            top += e.offsetTop;
        }while(e = e.offsetParent);

        return [left, top];
    }

    function jumpTo(id){    
        window.scrollTo(getPosition(id));
    }

</script>
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="jumpTo('contact');">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<h2><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></h2>
```

Comment: I think the issue isn't getting a clickable link to work on the same page, but reloading the page with the modified URL. Your answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to scroll on your element so URL doesn't change and when you reload the page has the starter URL.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the suggestion, may look into that although it sounds a bit expensive to replace what you would expect to be basic functionality with yet another script.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird because it is supposed to work. As others suggest, have a look at your error logs. In the mean time you can try this quick fix:

Instead of having `#contact` in your `<a>` you can put the full url using the help of php like this:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>


    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo getPageUrl(); ?>#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2 id="contact">Contact</h2>


</body>
</html>
<?php
    function getPageUrl(){
        return 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
?>
```

This should make your `<a>` look like this

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php#contact">Contact</a>
```